# How to return multiple tokens with Jison lexer

Tags: javascript, jison

I'm new to lexing and parsing so sorry if the title isn't clear enough.

Basically, I'm using Jison to parse some text and I am trying to get the lexer to comprehend indentation. Here's the bit in question:

```
(\r\n|\r|\n)+\s*      %{
                        parser.indentCount = parser.indentCount || [0];

                        var indentation = yytext.replace(/^(\r\n|\r|\n)+/, '').length;

                        if (indentation > parser.indentCount[0]) {
                           parser.indentCount.unshift(indentation);
                           return 'INDENT';
                        }

                        var tokens = [];

                        while (indentation < parser.indentCount[0]) {
                          tokens.push('DEDENT');
                          parser.indentCount.shift();
                        }

                        if (tokens.length) {
                           return tokens;
                        }

                        if (!indentation.length) {
                          return 'NEWLINE';
                        }
                      %}
```

So far, almost all of that works as expected. The one problem is the line where I attempt to return an array of `DEDENT` tokens. It appears that Jison is just converting that array into a string which causes me to get a parse error like `Expecting ........, got DEDENT,DEDENT`.

What I'm hoping I can do to get around this is manually push some `DEDENT` tokens onto the stack. Maybe with a function like `this.pushToken('DEDENT')` or something along those lines. But the Jison documentation is not so great and I could use some help.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

I seem to have been able to hack my way around this after looking at the generated parser code. Here's what seems to work...

```
if (tokens.length) {
  var args = arguments;

  tokens.slice(1).forEach(function () {
    lexer.performAction.apply(this, args);
  }.bind(this));

  return 'DEDENT';
}
```

This tricks the lexer into performing another action using the exact same input for each `DEDENT` we have in the stack, thus allowing it to add in the proper dedents. However, it feels gross and I'm worried there could be unforeseen problems.

I would still love it if anyone had any ideas on a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of days I ended up figuring out a better answer. Here's what it looks like:

```
(\r\n|\r|\n)+[ \t]*   %{
                        parser.indentCount = parser.indentCount || [0];
                        parser.forceDedent = parser.forceDedent || 0;

                        if (parser.forceDedent) {
                          parser.forceDedent -= 1;
                          this.unput(yytext);
                          return 'DEDENT';
                        }

                        var indentation = yytext.replace(/^(\r\n|\r|\n)+/, '').length;

                        if (indentation > parser.indentCount[0]) {
                           parser.indentCount.unshift(indentation);
                           return 'INDENT';
                        }

                        var dedents = [];

                        while (indentation < parser.indentCount[0]) {
                          dedents.push('DEDENT');
                          parser.indentCount.shift();
                        }

                        if (dedents.length) {
                           parser.forceDedent = dedents.length - 1;
                           this.unput(yytext);
                           return 'DEDENT';
                        }

                        return `NEWLINE`;
                      %}
```

Firstly, I modified my capture regex to make sure I wasn't inadvertently capturing extra newlines after a series of non-newline spaces.

Next, we make sure there are 2 "global" variables. `indentCount` will track our current indentation length. `forceDedent` will force us to return a `DEDENT` if it has a value above 0.

Next, we have a condition to test for a truthy value on `forceDedent`. If we have one, we'll decrement it by 1 and use the `unput` function to make sure we iterate on this same pattern at least one more time, but for this iteration, we'll return a `DEDENT`.

If we haven't returned, we get the length of our current indentation.

If the current indentation is greater than our most recent indentation, we'll track that on our `indentCount` variable and return an `INDENT`.

If we haven't returned, it's time to prepare to possible dedents. We'll make an array to track them.

When we detect a dedent, the user could be attempting to close 1 or more blocks all at once. So we need to include a `DEDENT` for as many blocks as the user is closing. We set up a loop and say that for as long as the current indentation is less than our most recent indentation, we'll add a `DEDENT` to our list and shift an item off of our `indentCount`.

If we tracked any dedents, we need to make sure all of them get returned by the lexer. Because the lexer can only return 1 token at a time, we'll return 1 here, but we'll also set our `forceDedent` variable to make sure we return the rest of them as well. To make sure we iterate on this pattern again and those dedents can be inserted, we'll use the `unput` function.

In any other case, we'll just return a `NEWLINE`.